# How can I remove the characters or text to show only the PID in terminal. Ubuntu/Linux terminal

Tags: sed

How can I remove the characters/texts from this output?
I've been trying to sed/cut but I cant really do it.

My command:

```
xprop -id $(xprop -root 32x '\t$0' _NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW | cut -f 2) _NET_WM_PID
```

**Output:**

```
_NET_WM_PID(CARDINAL) = 3239
```

**Expected output:**

```
3239
```

Comment: Pipe it to `awk '{print $NF}'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using `cut` alone. Note that the `cut` command has the argument `-d` which defaults to tab but you can pass other delimiter.

```
xprop -id $(xprop -root _NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW | cut -d\# -f2) _NET_WM_PID | cut -d\  -f3
```

Lets break this down into its parts, and start at the inside.

- `xprop -root _NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW | cut -d\# -f2` select the id, by using the pound symbol as delimiter for cut, the first field is everything before the `#` and the second field is everything behind the first `#`, here it is the id
- `$( ... )` is replaced by the result of the command inside the parens, here that is the id
- `xprop -id $( ... ) _NET_WM_PID | cut -d\  -f3`  the outer `xprop` result can be cutted at the space, which give use three fields:

  - _NET_WM_PID(CARDINAL)
  - =
  - the value (without leading space as one would get by using `=` as delimiter)
- Note that we use `-d\`  to specify "space as delimiter", we need to escape the space with a backslash.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -E 's#.*/([0-9]*).*#\1#g' file.txt
```

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained how the code you provided answers the question.